# Find a replace string inside a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

I am trying to find the nested string inside a div tag and replace the string with `jQuery`.

```js
$( ".short-features col-sm-4.inner" ).replaceWith( "<strong>Engine</strong> :</span> Manual</div>" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="short-features">
  <!-- Heading Area -->
  <div class="heading-panel">
    <h3 class="main-title text-left">Details</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <span><strong>Engine</strong> :</span> Automatic
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding"></div>
</div>
```

It's not working, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Nothing in your code contains the class `inner`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no `element` with the class `inner`, so you need to check that div has span or not? if yes, then replace it with new data

```
$( ".short-features .col-md-4" ).has('span').replaceWith( "<strong>Engine</strong> :</span> Manual</div>" );

//------------------^ forgot .---^check span--^then replace ---------------//
```

Working snippet

```js
$( ".short-features .col-md-4" ).has('span').replaceWith( "<strong>Engine</strong> :</span> Manual</div>" );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="short-features">
  <!-- Heading Area -->
  <div class="heading-panel">
    <h3 class="main-title text-left">Details</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <span><strong>Engine</strong> :</span> Automatic
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding"></div>
</div>
```

***Note:- Or you can*** add class `inner` to the div which has `<span>` in it and then you can go directly:

```
$( ".short-features .col-md-4.inner" ).replaceWith( "<strong>Engine</strong> :</span> Manual</div>" );
```

What you asked in comment for that you have to use [:contains() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$( ".short-features .col-md-4" ).has("span:contains('Engine')").replaceWith( "<strong>Engine</strong> :</span> Manual</div>" );
```

Working link:- https://jsfiddle.net/n37q169f/

Comment: The color is dynamic it's changes according to the page.

Comment: @sevoug  now you have to ask a new question for that. Current question is already answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there was no `element` with the class `inner`

you were also missing a `.` in your `jquery`

```
$(".short-features .col-sm-4.inner").replaceWith("<strong>Engine</strong> :</span> Manual</div>");
                   ^
                   was missing
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".short-features .col-sm-4.inner").replaceWith("<strong>Engine</strong> :</span> Manual</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="short-features">
  <!-- Heading Area -->
  <div class="heading-panel">
    <h3 class="main-title text-left">
      Details </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding inner"><span><strong>Engine</strong> :</span> Automatic</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 no-padding"></div>
</div>
```